# Ckeditor with PHPMailer - Empty Body Message

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ckeditor, phpmailer

so I added PHPMailer to my website and managed to make it work.
However, after adding Ckeditor to replace the "message / body" field - the emails are not being sent without any content.

**This is the index file where the form is located**

```
<?php
include '../../../../config.php';

$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", "$username", "$password");
$query = "SELECT * FROM uni_clients ORDER BY clients_id";
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
     
<!-- this is for the button to disable it if checkboxes are unchecked -->
<script>
function toggle(source) {
checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('single_select');
for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}
 </script>
    
 <script>
function terms_changed(termsCheckBox){
    //If the checkbox has been checked
    if(termsCheckBox.checked){
        //Set the disabled property to FALSE and enable the button.
        document.getElementById("bulk_email").disabled = false;
    } else{
        //Otherwise, disable the submit button.
        document.getElementById("bulk_email").disabled = true;
    }
}
</script>
         


<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>


  <title>Send Bulk Email </title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="include/modules/massmail/styles.css">
 </head>
 
 
 <body>
      
  <br />
  <div class="container">
   <h3 align="center"><strong>Choose users from the list</strong></h3>
   
   <br />
   

<!-- Creating the table that displays the users in the database and their details -->
   <div class="class="table-wrapper>
    <table class="fl-table">
     <tr>
      <th>Customer's Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Select</th>
      <th>Action</th>
     </tr>
     
     
     <?php
     $count = 0;
     foreach($result as $row)
     {
      $count++;
      echo '
      <tr>
       <td>'.$row["clients_name"]." " .$row["clients_surname"].'</td>
       <td>'.$row["clients_email"].'</td>
       <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="single_select" id="checkbox" onclick="terms_changed(this)" class="single_select" data-email="'.$row["clients_email"].'" data-name="'.$row["clients_name"].'" />
       </td>
       <td><button type="button" name="email_button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs email_button" id="'.$count.'" data-email="'.$row["clients_email"].'" data-name="'.$row["clients_name"].'" data-action="single">Send Single</button></td>
      </tr>
      ';
     }
     ?>
    
     </td>
    </table>
   </div>
   <input  type="checkbox"  onClick="toggle(this),terms_changed(this)" id="checkbox" /> Choose All Users <br/><br>
  </div>
  
  

  <div class="container">
      
   <br />



   <div style="text-align:center">
       <h3> <strong>Email Subject</strong></h3>
       <input type="text" id="subject" placeholder="subject" value="" /> <br><br>
       
<!-- This is where the issue starts after Ckeditor -->
       <h3><strong> Email Body </strong></h3>
       <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="5" cols="5" >
</textarea>

<script src="../../../../admin-panel/files/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>CKEDITOR.replace("message")</script>
              
     
    <button type="button" style="background:orange;width:25%" id="bulk_email"  name="bulk_email" class="btn btn-info email_button" id="bulk_email" data-action="bulk"disabled>Send Emails</button>
  
   </div>
  </div>
  
  
  
 </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.email_button').click(function(){
  $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  var action = $(this).data("action");
  var email_data = [];
  if(action == 'single')
  {
   email_data.push({
    email: $(this).data("email"),
    name: $(this).data("name"),
    subject: $(subject).val(),
    message: $(message).val() 
   });
  }
  else
  {
   $('.single_select').each(function(){
    if($(this). prop("checked") == true)
    {
     email_data.push({
      email: $(this).data("email"),
      name: $(this).data('name'),
      subject: $(subject).val(),
    message: $(message).val()
     });
    }
   });
  }
  
  $.ajax({
   url:"include/modules/massmail/send_mail.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{email_data:email_data},
   beforeSend:function(){
    $('#'+id).html('Sending...');
    $('#'+id).addClass('btn-danger');
   },
   success:function(data){
    if(data = 'ok')
    {
     $('#'+id).text('Success');
     $('#'+id).removeClass('btn-danger');
     $('#'+id).removeClass('btn-info');
     $('#'+id).addClass('btn-success');
    }
    else
    {
     $('#'+id).text(data);
    }
    $('#'+id).attr('disabled', false);
   }
   
  });
 });
});
</script>
```

**This is the send_mail.php page (for phpmailer) :**

```
<?
if(isset($_POST['email_data']))
{
include  '../../../../config.php';
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
 $output = '';
 foreach($_POST['email_data'] as $row)
 {
  $mail = new PHPMailer;
  $mail->IsSMTP();        //Sets Mailer to send message using SMTP
  $mail->Host = $mailHost;  //Sets the SMTP hosts of your Email hosting, this for Godaddy
  $mail->Port = $mailPort;        //Sets the default SMTP server port
  $mail->SMTPAuth = $mailSMTPAuth;       //Sets SMTP authentication. Utilizes the Username and Password variables
  $mail->Username = $mailUsername;     //Sets SMTP username
  $mail->Password = $mailPassword;     //Sets SMTP password
  $mail->SMTPSecure = $mailSMTPSecure;       //Sets connection prefix. Options are "", "ssl" or "tls"
  $mail->From = $mailFrom;   //Sets the From email address for the message
  $mail->FromName = $mailFromName;     //Sets the From name of the message
  $mail->AddAddress($row["email"], $row["name"]); //Adds a "To" address
  $mail->WordWrap = 50;       //Sets word wrapping on the body of the message to a given number of characters
  $mail->IsHTML(true);       //Sets message type to HTML
  $mail->Subject = $row["subject"]; 
  $mail->Body = $row["message"];

  $mail->AltBody = '';

  $result = $mail->Send();      //Send an Email. Return true on success or false on error

  if($result["code"] == '400')
  {
   $output .= html_entity_decode($result['full_error']);
  }

 }
 if($output == '')
 {
  echo 'ok';
 }
 else
 {
  echo $output;
 }
}

?>
```

I'm so thankful that you made it so far, I know the answer might be easier than I think, I'm still learning.

I am sharing 2 images with you now to show you the page and the email that I received[screenshot - Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slCCK.png)

[Empty Email/ body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4JHh.png)

Comment: Within your Javascript of your form, you are using the following:

`email: $(this).data("email"), name: $(this).data("name"), subject: $(subject).val(), message: $(message).val()`
Is there a reason why you use a different way of getting the data for email and name than for subject and message? For me it looks like, `subject` and `message` could be undefined

Comment: You're using a very old version of PHPMailer, and sending very inefficiently - driving a send to a list from client-side JS is never going to of a good job. Take a look at [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps).

Comment: @Tim - I have to use another method because the first didn't work at all, the page was not sending messages at all, because it couldn't grab the subject and the message. I read on Stackoverflow about this and I gave it a try, it worked;
The message and the subject are being sent to the Mailer page, but the message stopped showing after enabling Kceditor

Comment: @Synchro, Yes I am aware of that, thank you for pointing it out,I will make sure to update it. 
However, the pages were working fine until I enabled Kceditor, so there's something I am missing somewhere, I don't seem to be able to find it

Answer (score 0):

may be this line `$mail->AltBody = '';`

Remove `$mail->AltBody`, or

set a sentence: `$mail->AltBody = "To get this email correctly, use an email viewer with HTML support"`

And I take the test

Comment: Thank you for answering Neylton, I tried that as well, It didn't work.
I also followed their official documentation and did exactly what they said, It still won't take the content from CKeditor